# nestjs: @Transform does not take effect in typeorm entity?

Tags: nestjs

When the query result Entity[] is directly returned from the controller, the @Transform defined in the entity can take effect normally, but when returning data such as {datalist: Entity[]}, it is found that the method in @Transform is not executed

[Google Translate ~]

> entity

```
import { Transform } from 'class-transformer';
import {CreateDateColumn, Entity} from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 't_articles' })
export class ArticleEntity {
 ...
  @Transform((v) => {
    console.log(123);
    return new Date(v).toLocaleString();
  })
  @CreateDateColumn()
  create_time: Date;
 ...
 }
```

> controller

```
const [datalist, count] = await this.articleRepository.findAndCount({skip, take, where});
return datalist // ===> transformed
return {datalist} // ===> untransformed, and '123' is not printed
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NestJs make sure you have:

```
    app.useGlobalPipes(
        new ValidationPipe({
            transform: true
        })
    );
```

Comment: As they state NestJS in the title, body, and tags, it's pretty certain that they are using NestJS.